# Directed weighted graph walk

Tags: theory, graph-theory, random-walk

I have a connected directed weighted graph. The edge weights represent probabilities of moving between vertices; weights for all edges emanating from a vertex sum up to one. The graph contains two sinks: A and B. For each vertex in the graph, I want to know the probability that a walk originating there will reach A and the same for B. What kind of problem is this? How do I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is of the algebra kind. For a path starting at a vertex, the probability of reaching A is the average of probabilities of reaching A from each of its neighbouring vertices, weighted by the edge weights. Let's put this into more concrete terms.

Let *P* be the adjacency matrix for the graph. That is, *P<sub>i,j</sub>* is the probability of moving from vertex *i* to vertex *j*. Set *P<sub>A,A</sub>* = 1. If we take a vector of probabilities assigned to each vertex and multiply it by *P*, then the resulting vector contains a weighted average of each vertex's neighbours. What we are looking for is a vector *v*, such that *P v = v* and *v<sub>A</sub> = 1*.

This vector *v* is the eigenvector of *P* corresponding to the eigenvalue of 1. Does *P* always have such an eigenvalue? Fortunately, the [Perron-Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron-Frobenius_theorem) tells us that it does, and that this is the largest eigenvalue of *P*. The solution is then to form the adjacency matrix *P* and find the eigenvector corresponding to its largest eigenvalue.

There is also an approximate solution. If we take a vector *x* of vertex probabilities, with *x<sub>A</sub>* = 1, and the other elements set to 0, then *P<sup>k</sup> x* will converge to *v* as *k* goes to infinity. *P<sup>k</sup>* might be easier to compute for small values of *k* than the eigenvector.

---

### Example

Let's look at the following simple graph:

[image: diagram]

If we order the vertices alphabetically, then the matrix *P* corresponding to the graph is:

[image]

This matrix has an eigenvalue equal to 1, and the corresponding eigenvector is: [1 0 70/79 49/79]. That is, the exact probability of reaching *A* from *C* is 70/79, and from *D* it is 49/79. If you work out the answer for *B*, it comes out to 9/79 and 30/79, which is exactly what we expect.

The value of *P<sup>16</sup>* [1 0 0 0] is approximately [1 0 0.886 0.62] and is correct to 6 decimal places.